# Scaladoc hide inherited members by default

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I'm using `sbt doc` to generate documentation for a Scala project.

Using the default settings the documentation automatically shows inherited members as in the following screenshot.

[image: Showing all inherited]

Ideally I would like to generate documentation which hides all the inherited members by default as below.

[image: Hiding all inherited]

How can I approach generating the documentation such that it only shows explicitly defined members?

Answer (score 1):

`scaladoc -help` yields nothing germane, and neither does the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc/Settings.scala).  You're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes `scaladoc -help` doesn't help a whole lot. However, I have seen other documentation which achieves the effect I am after. There must be a way to do it.